# IndexError: Invalid index to scalar variable with ConvertOneHot

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, error-handling, scipy, data-science

```
data = np.genfromtxt('TrainingSet.csv',invalid_raise=False)  # Training data
test_data = np.genfromtxt('TestSet.csv',invalid_raise=False)  # Test data


def convertOneHot(inp):
    y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in inp])
    y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
    for i,j in enumerate(y):
        y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
        y_onehot[i][j]=1
    return (y,y_onehot)


x_train=np.ndarray([ in[1::] for i in data])
y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)

x_test=np.ndarray([ i[1::] for i in test_data])
y_test,y_test_onehot = convertOneHot(test_data)
```

[My error message is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XaS5.png)

I have seen problems with this error solved in other threads, however none of the workarounds or fixes i have attempted seem to work for me.

Comment: It is better to add the error message here in a block.

Comment: Is that your *actual* code?  Surely `in[1::]` would result in a `SyntaxError`, because `in` is a reserved word.

Comment: hi warren- that 'n' was a typo made, and was not present when i received the error message. i have removed it an reran my code, and am receiving the same error posted above

Comment: It looks like you expect `data` to be a two-dimensional array. Is it? Check `data.shape` and `data.dtype`.  If `data` is actually one-dimensional, then `i` (in the list comprehension) will be a scalar and you'll get the error message that you reported.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. data.shape returns  (63000,), while data.dtype returns float64. How can i have the csv input read as an array?

Comment: Well, it *is* an array--a numpy one-dimensional array.  That's what `genfromtxt` created.  What does `'TrainingSet.csv'` look like?

Comment: 'TrainingSet.csv' is a csv file with column delimiter ",", and row delimiter "\n". The file contains 63000 rows and 1445 columns when read correctly

Comment: Then you must use the argument `delimiter=','` in `genfromtxt`.  The default delimiter is white space.

Comment: I tried this earlier, and experience this error:            /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:1772: ConversionWarning: Some errors were detected !
    Line #14 (got 1 columns instead of 1445)
    Line #54 (got 1 columns instead of 1445)
    Line #100 (got 1 columns instead of 1445)
    Line #157 (got 1 columns instead of 1445)...            

there are more instaces of this error, but i did not want to include the entire error message

Comment: Have you actually looked at the file in an editor?  It sounds like your data file has some glitches, or it is not quite as simple as 63000 rows and 1445 columns. The first error is at line 14, so take a look at the first 20 lines to see if anything unexpected is in the file.

Comment: Yes, I have quite extensively. The file opens in excel and does not appear to have any glitches, unless some  missing values could be causing the glitching

Comment: *"The file opens in excel..."*  How about in a text editor?  Are the fields all numbers, or are there text fields?  Can you post the first 20 lines here (or somewhere)?  Anyway, now that the problem is narrowed down to simply reading the data into an array, you could edit the question (and title) to reflect that.

Comment: the file also opens fine in text editors, i have used gedit as well as wordpad and can open the data with no problems.

Comment: I cannot even include a full line of data here due to the character limit, but i have posted some http://freetexthost.com/g2mp1dlckb here. The data contains a mix of integers, numbers, and strings